# Own PreferencePage: Set and get values - storeValues() is never called

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm creating my own PreferencePage for Eclipse for a RCP application.
For the FileFieldEditor I want the value to be stored and get it later on in another class.
For this I do:

```java
private void initializeDefaults() {
    IPreferenceStore store = getPreferenceStore();
    subversionPathEditor.setStringValue(store.getString(FIELD_SUBVERSION_PATH));
}
```

The Activator class implements AbstractUIPlugin and in the init() method of the PreferencePage the preference store is set:

```java
public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
    setPreferenceStore(Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());
}
```

Values are stored using the storeValues() method accoring to the 
[Eclipse Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/preferences_prefs_implement.htm?cp=2_0_4_3_1):

```java
private void storeValues() {
    IPreferenceStore store = Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
    store.setValue("SUBVERSION_PATH", subversionPathEditor.getStringValue());
}
```

And here is the problem: Eclipse is telling me the method is never used (locally).
So the value can't be in the PreferenceStore.

What I am doing wrong?

(Tell me, if you need more code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation page carefully it says the `storeValues` method has to be called when OK and Apply are pressed.

You do this by overriding `performOk`:

```java
@Override
public boolean performOk()
{
  storeValues();

  super.performOk();
}
```

You can also override `performApply` but the default action is to call `performOk` so it is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Thanks! It works. But even after your answer I can not read that clearly out of the documentation page. But thats probably only me.

Comment: I agree that the documentation page is rather poor.